# Tkinter only calls after_idle once

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter, so I apologize if this is easy, but I have search for a couple of hours and can't figure it out.  What I want to do is after the mainloop is idle, I always want to call the function checkForGroupUpdates().  When I run the code below, it only runs once.  I can't figure out to have it run every time the mainloop is idle.  I appreciate the help.

```
from Tkinter import *
import random

class Network(Frame):  
    """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                               
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):      
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self.makeWidgets()    

    def makeWidgets(self):                       
        """ Make the time label. """
        self._canvas = Canvas(self, width=600, height=400)
        self._canvas.pack()

    def checkForGroupUpdates(self):
        print "checking"
        h=0
        this=10
        while this>.0001:
            this=random.random()
            print h
            h=h+1
        print "checked"


def main():
    root = Tk()
    nw = Network(root)
    nw.pack(side=TOP)

    root.after_idle(nw.checkForGroupUpdates)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "every time the mainloop is idle"? It is idle most of the time, except when you are clicking buttons.

Comment: Yes, so ideally I would like the above program to essentially continuously run checkForGroupUpdates() as the mainloop should be idle most of the time.  I would like the checkForGroupUpdates() to be run every time that the mainloop is idle.

Comment: So, you want it to run thousands of times a second when the program is doing nothing else? Does it _really_ need to be run that often, or can it run just a few times a second? Having it run continuously while the app is idle rarely is any more useful than just calling it a few times a second.

Comment: @Brian Oakley's answer is correct, but if you really did have time-critical code going on that needs to take up as many resources as possible, with as little delay as possible to allow the GUI to update itself, `after_idle` is indeed the function you want. I've posted an answer to explain how to use it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@user1763510, notice that in Bryan Oakley's answer, he has `checkForGroupUpdates` call `self.after` again. This is because `self.after` only does a *single* call, so getting repeated calls requires having it call itself within the function that gets called by the first call. This way, it keeps repeatedly calling itself.

The same goes for the `after_idle()` function. You have to have `checkForGroupUpdates` call `after_idle()` again at the bottom.

Here is the documentation for `after`, `after_idle`, etc. There is even a little example in the `after` description, which makes it all clear.

Documentation: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm

Example from link above, under the `after`description:

```
#Method 1
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.poll() # start polling

    def poll(self):
        ... do something ...
        self.master.after(100, self.poll)
```

To use `after_idle` instead, it would look like this:

```
#Method 2
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.poll() # start polling

    def poll(self):
        ... do something ...
        self.master.update_idletasks()
        self.master.after_idle(self.poll)
```

Notice the addition of the `self.master.update_idletasks()` line. This draws the GUI and handles button presses and things. Otherwise, `after_idle()` will suck up all resources and not let the GUI self-update properly in the `mainloop()`.

An alternative to using

```
        self.master.update_idletasks()
        self.master.after_idle(self.poll)
```

is to use:

```
        #Method 3
        self.master.update_idletasks()
        self.master.after(0, self.poll)
```

Using `self.master.after(0, self.poll)` is my preferred technique, as it allows me to easily change the 0 to something else if I decide I don't need to run self.poll constantly. By increasing the delay time to at least 1 ms, you no longer need to call `self.master.update_idletasks()` at all. So, this works too:

```
        #Method 4
        self.master.after(1, self.poll)
```

Also notice that for all examples above, calling `self.poll()` in the `__init__` function is what kicks it all off, and storing `master` into `self.master` is necessary simply so that inside `poll` you can call the `after` or `after_idle` function via `self.master.after_idle`, for example.

**Q: Is this stable/does it work?**
A: I ran a test code using Method 3 just above for ~21 hrs, and it ran stably the whole time, allowing the GUI to be usable and all.

**Q: What is the speed comparison for each method above?**
A:

- Method 1: (I didn't speed test it)
- Method 2: ~0.44 ms/iteration
- Method 3: ~0.44 ms/iteration
- Method 4: ~1.61 ms/iteration

**Q: Which is my preferred method?**
A: Method 3 or 4.

Comment: It's a little dangerous to call `after_idle` from a function called by `after_idle`. What can happen is that you never give tkinter a chance to fully drain the idle queue, which means it never gets a chance to service any other events that might be pending.

Comment: Isn't that what `update_idletasks()` solves? I've run a quick test and it seems to work as I've presented above. For `...do something...` I am printing "test", and while printing that in the background, the GUI I've built does display.

Comment: You have to remember that this function was called by the tkinter process that services the idle queue. So, imagine a function that takes one item off (ie: this function), executes it, then checks to see if there is anything else in the queue. If there is, it processes it. So, before it does that check you're adding something new to the queue. It never runs out of items on the queue beause for every item taken off, another is added. The nested call to `update_idletasks` may exhaust the list, but you're immediately adding a new one before the current pass through the queue is finished.

Comment: Ok, can I somehow write a loop to keep calling `update_idletasks()` until there are no more tasks on the queue, and *then* call `after_idle()`? What I really want is this: run my main code, which is an infinite loop repeatedly checking for new serial data for live data plotting, if serial data exists, read and plot it, if serial data is not waiting on the input buffer, update the GUI. This needs to run as fast as the computer can make it go, basically, under worst-case scenarios when I'm receiving and plotting lots of data.

Comment: I'm also confused by the documentation then for `after_idle`, as the documentation itself implies that the after_idle callback is only called *after* all events are processed and cleared off the queue. "Registers a callback that is called when the system is idle. The callback will be called there are no more events to process in the mainloop. The callback is only called once for each call to after_idle." (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm)

Comment: Right. But while it is in the middle of processing an item on the queue, you add another item to the queue. The queue never fully empties. It isn't done processing all the items in the queue until the current function returns, and you're adding a new item to the queue _before_ it returns.

Comment: _"Ok, can I somehow write a loop to keep calling update_idletasks() until there are no more tasks on the queue, and then call after_idle()? "_ - the normal way to do this is something like `self.master.after(1, self.master.after_idle, ...). This gives tkinter a tiny gap after processing the queue before something new gets added.

Comment: Bryan, I updated my answer w/some more info, and I tested Method 3 above for a full 21 hrs, with the GUI & background tasks (printing an incrementing counter, and timestamp, in the callback function) running perfectly stably. No problems. So, It seems to me to be a perfectly viable solution. I'm about to use my "Method 3" in a full GUI project, so if I have any issues I'll make note of it here, but I really think it works well. At a minimum, Method 4 is a fallback. In either case, I think my answer provides additional insight beyond what you've posted in your answer, so hopefully it's useful.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of calling the function all the time when the app is idle, you should just call it once every fraction of a second. For example, if you want to check 10 times every second you would do something like this:

```
def checkForGroupUpdates(self):
    <do whatever you want>
    self.after(100, self.checkForGroupUpdates)
```

Once you call that function once, it will arrange for itself to be called again in 100ms. This will continue until the program exits. If the program goes "non-idle" (ie: while responding to a button click), this function will pause since tkinter is single-threaded. Once the program goes idle again, the check will continue.