# How can I automatically update my listbox in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I've seen a couple posts similar to my question, but not exactly this, so apologies if this is a repeat question.

I'm using tkinter to read a folder, create a listbox that lists all the files (they're all going to be .tif files), and the user selects the image they want to view. Unfortunately files will be added and removed so I would like to update my listbox automatically. Here's some of the code I have so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

file_path = "C:/Users/USX27512/Desktop/Python UI/Test_TIFFs"
root = Tk()

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        os.chdir(file_path)
        self.grid()
        self.canv = Canvas(self, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.canv.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=5, sticky=N)
        self.canv.config(width=500, height=500)
        self.canv.config(highlightthickness=0, background="black")
        self.view_files()

    def view_files(self):
        lb = Listbox(self, height=20)
        lb.update_idletasks()
        files = sorted(os.listdir(file_path), key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(os.path.join(file_path, x)))
        for file in files:
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(file_path, file)):
                lb.insert(END, file)

        lb.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.on_double)
        lb.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=NW)

    def on_double(self, event):
        widget = event.widget
        selection = widget.curselection()
        value = widget.get(selection[0])

        sbarV = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
        sbarH = Scrollbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        sbarV.config(command=self.canv.yview)
        sbarH.config(command=self.canv.xview)
        self.canv.config(yscrollcommand=sbarV.set)
        self.canv.config(xscrollcommand=sbarH.set)
        sbarV.grid(row=2, column=6, sticky=N+S)
        sbarH.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan= 5, sticky=E+W)

        self.im = Image.open(value)
        image_width, image_height = self.im.size
        self.canv.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, image_width, image_height))
        self.im2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
        self.imgtag = self.canv.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=self.im2)

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking how to automatically check for filesystem changes? Are you asking  how to update a listbox after it's been created? What _specific_ problem are you having with this?

Comment: @BryanOakley I know how to modify the listbox, I believe I'm looking for the automatic check for file system changes. My understanding of tkinter is that the mainloop sits and waits for a change, maybe it's a button press a keyboard entry and then it loops through and makes the changes and then waits again. So how do I get the file system change to tell the mainloop to act on that change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499082/tkinter-only-calls-after-idle-once). From that function, I can check the list and update it as needed.