# Using the after-method with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm having troubles using the "after" method in my GUI.
The goal is to create a loop, which calculates "flow" with given input variables.
So far I didn't manage to get my code running, with the documentation on "after" or this post [Tkinter only calls after_idle once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499082/tkinter-only-calls-after-idle-once/38817470#38817470)

My Code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkMessageBox

class Regeln():
    def __init__(self):
        bla=1
    def lesen(self,faktor,stromdichte,flaeche,anzahl,elektronen,konzentration):
        self.faktor=faktor
        self.stromdichte=stromdichte
        self.flaeche=flaeche
        self.anzahl=anzahl
        self.elektronen=elektronen
        self.konzentration=konzentration
        try:
            self.faktor=float(self.faktor)
            self.stromdichte=float(self.stromdichte)
            self.flaeche=float(self.flaeche)
            self.anzahl=float(self.anzahl)
            self.elektronen=float(self.elektronen)
            self.konzentration=float(self.konzentration)
        except:
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Achtung!","Nur Zahlen eingeben!")
        try:
            1/(self.faktor*self.stromdichte*self.flaeche*self.anzahl*self.elektronen*self.konzentration)         
        except:
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Achtung!","Nur Werte größer 0 eingeben!")
        self.algorithmus()

    def algorithmus(self):
        flow=self.faktor*self.stromdichte*self.elektronen*60/(96485.34*self.konzentration*0.75/100)*self.flaeche*self.anzahl/1000
        print flow

        self.after(1500,self.algorithmus)
```

With this I get an "AttributeError". Anybody has any idea how to get it running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`after` is a method available on all tkinter widgets. In your specific case, `self` is not a widget, so naturally it won't have this method.

You need to call `after` from an existing widget. For example, if you initially created your GUI with something like this:

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

You can later call `after` like this:

```
root.after(...)
```

Comment: Thank you, `root.after(...)` was the right hint. The algorithm is now working.